# About numbers to the powers of imaginary numbers

Tags: real-numbers, exponentiation

I once saw a problem which asks for the real and imaginary parts $(i^i)^i$. The problem also implied that there are several solutions to this. However I am very confused, $(i^i)$ is a real number so isn't its imaginary part just that real number raised to the power of $i$?
Please help thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$i^i=\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^i=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
therefore $$\left(i^i\right)^i=\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^i=e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-i$$
and so $\Re\left(\left(i^i\right)^i\right)=0$ and $\Im\left(\left(i^i\right)^i\right)=-1$

Comment: This answer is ok and clear. (+1) I don't know why de down vote.

Comment: @User thank you, I'm used to random downvotes, this server is sick

Comment: (Late response, I just stumbled upon this) I didn't downvote, but here's one reason why I think someone could have. You seem to be saying $\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^i = \exp\left(i \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot i\right)$ when in general, you can't always combine complex powers willy-nilly "in the usual sense" as if they are real numbers. Evaluating a general expression for $\left(i^i\right)^i$ is a lot more complicated and involves using the complex logarithm definition and the fact that $z^c = \exp(c \log(z))$ for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Maybe some other stuff depending on what OP knows.

Comment: And another issue, maybe to the OP too, is that we don't know what kind of answer the OP needs, like if they need a general solution or a specific solution that requires a certain branch of a logarithm. The complex logarithm isn't well-defined in $\mathbb{C}$, but your answer might work depending on what branch you are using.

Comment: @Accelerator thank you for your opinion, I understand what you are saying and what could be wrong in my answer. Though, if the downvoters (2 by the moment I'm writing this) thought the same as you, could have just pointed it out instead of downvoting and leaving.

Comment: Yep, no problem. Usually to be safe, when I see powers for complex numbers, my go-to is using the [definition](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Analysis_-_A_Visual_and_Interactive_Introduction_(Ponce_Campuzano)/03%3A_Chapter_3/3.05%3A_The_Complex_Power_Function) $z^c = \exp(c \log(z)) = \exp\left(c \ln|z| + i\operatorname{arg}(z)\right)$ where arg is an element of whichever interval I'm dealing with.

Comment: Typo, I meant $\exp(c \ln|z| + ic \operatorname{arg}(z))$.

Answer (score 1):

> @Zima 's answer clearly answers this question, with the appropriate principal arguments. However, in this text (not answer) I am going talk more about your statement of "*several solutions*".

Recall that polar plane is closed and angles following $\theta + 2\pi$ repeat the same output for $\theta$; $\sin{\theta}$, $\cos{\theta}$. Ie. $\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} = \sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi\right)} = \sin{\dfrac{5\pi}{2}}$ and $\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} = \cos{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi\right)} = \cos{\dfrac{5\pi}{2}}$.

This property exists within the complex world as well, however, we note it as "branching" and equivalent to your multivalued solutions, since the polar form $\displaystyle e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}$. In practice, this would mean;

$$\left(e^{i\pi/2}\right)^i = i^i = \left(e^{i5\pi/2}\right)^i
\\\iff i^i = e^{-2n\pi - \pi/2}, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

However, note that $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ is still the **principal** argument for $i$. Any other angle that has equivalent output to $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, would classified under $\underbrace{\text{general arguments}}_{\theta = 2n\pi + \pi/2}$. See [Complex Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)).

> I assume this is what your *problem <s>also</s> implied that there are several solutions*. However, I am still confused, since this is not required to answer the question. Your problem *asks for the real and imaginary parts (i^i)^i*, which I assume would be in rectangular form; $0 + (-1)i$ only. Did the question explicitly ask you to state all possible arguments somewhere else?

Comment: I would like to know the downvote please. I can then correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}(i^i)^i & = i^{i\times i} \\
& = i^{-1}\\
& =e^{-i(2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi}, (k\in\mathbb Z)\\
& =-i\end{align}$$

If on the other hand you meant $i^{i^i}$, we have:
$$\begin{align} i^{i^i} & = i^{e^{(i(2m+\frac{1}{2})\pi)i}} \\
& = i^{e^{-(2m+\frac{1}{2})\pi}}\\
& = e^{i[(2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi e^{-(2m+\frac{1}{2})\pi}]}, (m,n\in\mathbb Z)\end{align}$$

for the top answer the real part is obviously $0$ and the imaginary part $-1$; for the bottom answer:

$${\frak Re} (i^{i^i})=\cos((2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi e^{-(2m+\frac{1}{2})\pi}), (m,n\in\mathbb Z)\\{\frak Im} (i^{i^i})=\sin((2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi e^{-(2m+\frac{1}{2})\pi}), (m,n\in\mathbb Z)$$

Comment: $(i^i)^i=i^{2i}$ ??????

Comment: Pretty sure this is a good answer

Comment: Yea this is what im looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: No worries :). It'd be great if you select the answer because I joined today and your question is my first one! :)